# Minutes/seconds countdown timer not ticking down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple timer in JS that starts at 25 minutes and counts down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     updateClock();
     var timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock(), 1000);
    });

    var ms = 1500000;
    var minutes = Math.floor(ms / 1000 / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60);

    function updateClock() {
     ms -= 1000;
     if (ms <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
     };
     $('#minutes').html(minutes);
     $('#seconds').html(seconds);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minutes"></div>
 <div id="seconds"></div>
```

I can't figure out why the page only displays 25 and 0, and never ticks down. Am I using setInterval() incorrectly?

Comment: Try: `setInterval(updateClock, 1000)`

Comment: Tried that, still did not work; thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: you are not updating the values of minutes and seconds inside `updateClock()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to calculate the value of `minutes` and `seconds` inside your `updateClock()` function. At the moment, they're never updated from the initial value.

Also, when setting the interval, do not add the parentheses to the function name, otherwise it simply passes a reference to the return value, not the function itself:

```js
var timeInterval;
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    updateClock();
    timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
});

var ms = 1500000;

function updateClock() 
{
    ms -= 1000;
    
    var minutes = Math.floor(ms / 1000 / 60),
        seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60);
    
    if (ms <= 0) 
    {
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
    };
    
    $('#minutes').html(minutes);
    $('#seconds').html(seconds);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="seconds"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you explain the part about not adding parentheses to the function name a little more, though? What do you mean by "it simply passes a reference to the return value"?

Comment: No problem: If you add parentheses inside of the function name for `setInterval()`, Javascript will pass the **return value** of that function to `setInterval`, rather than calling the function every `x` milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to update minutes and seconds again.

```
function updateClock() {
    ms -= 1000;
    if (ms <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timeInterval);
    };
    minutes = Math.floor(ms / 1000 / 60);
    seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60);
    $('#minutes').html(minutes);
    $('#seconds').html(seconds);
}
```